# URL rewrite in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, permalinks

How can I redirect http://www.mywebsite.com/confirm-registration/?registration_date=1405281684&email_address=email@googlemail.com to http://www.mywebsite.com/blog/confirm-registration/?registration_date=1405281684&email_address=email@googlemail.com through htccess ?

*registration_date and email_address values will be dynamic in the URL.

I have tried...

```
RewriteRule http://www.mywebsite.com/confirm-registration/?registration_date=^([a-zA-Z0-9])\$&email_address=^([a-zA-Z0-9])\$ http://www.mywebsite.com/confirm-registration/?registration_date=$1&email_address=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Thanks in advance,

~ Dipak G.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: @anubhava not yet. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You need to do some research and show some effort of your own.

Comment: @anubhava RewriteRule http://www.mywebsite.com/confirm-registration/?registration_date=^([a-zA-Z0-9])\$&email_address=^([a-zA-Z0-9])\$ http://www.mywebsite.com/confirm-registration/?registration_date=$1&email_address=$2 [QSA,NC,L]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RewriteRule` is only used for matching `REQUEST_URI` and that doesn't include protocol, domain name or query string.

You can use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/confirm-registration/ /blog/confirm-registration
```

Comment: I have tried your answer but when I open  http://www.mywebsite.com/confirm-registration/?registration_date=1405281684&email_address=email@googlemail.com in the browser, it's not redirecting to http://www.mywebsite.com/blog/confirm-registration/?registration_date=1405281684&email_address=email@googlemail.com ?

Comment: Comment out `RewriteCond` line and retest.

Comment: Add a line here: `RedirectMatch foo /bar` and then open `http://example.com/foo` to see if you get `http://example.com/bar` or not

Comment: Ok try: `RedirectMatch /confirm-registration/ /blog/confirm-registration` rule

Comment: This redirects but getting 'This webpage has a redirect loop' - why?

Comment: Try this instead: `RedirectMatch ^/confirm-registration/ /blog/confirm-registration`

Comment: Finally `RedirectMatch ^/confirm-registration/ /blog/confirm-registration` did the trick. Thank you.